Is every geodesic constant-speed?
I am learning differential geometry with "Pressley, Elementary Differential Geometry".
He establishes that (1) geodesics are curves of constant speed, and that (2) every meridian on a surface of revolution is a geodesic.
I tried to see that for myself on the unit paraboloid $$z=x^2+y^2$$
and the meridian that extends along the x axis given by $$\alpha(t)=(t,0,t^2)$$
But since $$||\alpha'(t)||=\sqrt{1+4t^2}\neq 1 ,$$
the meridian is not traversed at constant speed, and therefore cannot be a geodesic. How do I reconcile (1) and (2)?

If we split hairs, a geodesic is a path, a mapping from an interval into a surface. By contrast, a meridian is a curve, the image of a path. To reconcile, we need to parametrize meridians at constant speed.

Notice that in (2) he’s referring to (the image of) a curve, not a parametrized curve. Many of us are sloppy and refer to a curve — with no parametrization in sight — as a geodesic if it can be parametrized so as to be a geodesic. Some (not including me) refer to such a curve as a pre-geodesic.

Finding the arc-length parametrization seems to be a tough problem, at least for the path above - maybe there isn't? But then, how do we know the path (=meridian) is a geodesic?

Whether you can find an explicit formula for the arclength parametrization or not, any regular curve always has (abstractly) such a reparametrization.

So I shouldn't be checking for constant speed, since any regular curve can be re-parametrized to be constant speed anyway? My misunderstanding probably comes from the statement "any geodesic has constant speed" which I misinterpreted as being valid in both directions, ie geodesic <=> constant speed.

A geodesic is a parameterized curve whose geodesic curvature is zero. You can check whether $\alpha$ is a geodesic by computing its geodesic curvature.

Upshot from the comments: A geodesic always has constant speed, but not every constant-speed curve is a geodesic. The real feature which distinguishes a geodesic and some other curve seems to be the gedoesic curvature $\kappa_g$, which if zero, yields a geodesic. That curve, as an added "bonus", will be traversed at constant speed. The reverse however is not true, see below.
Example: Let $\sigma(r,\phi)=(r\cos\phi,r\sin\phi,r^2)$ be some patch on the unit paraboloid, $\alpha_1(t)=(t,0,t^2)$ a meridian, and $\alpha_2(t)=(\cos(t),\sin(t),1)$ a unit circle at $z=1$. It is easy to check that $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$ $\in \sigma$.


Is the meridian $\alpha_1$ a geodesic on $\sigma$?
Even though $||\alpha_1'(t)||=\sqrt{1+4t^2}$ is not constant, $\alpha_1$ is a regular curve (no kinks or sharp edges) and therefore can be reparametrized as constant speed: $||\widetilde{\alpha}_1'(t)||=v$ for some $v>0$.
How about geodesic cuvature $\kappa_g$?
$$\kappa_g=\frac{\alpha_1''\cdot(\vec{n}\times\alpha'_1)}{||\alpha_1'||^3},$$ where $\vec{n}$ is the unit normal of the paraboloid:
$$\vec{n}(r,\phi)=\frac{\sigma_r\times\sigma_\phi}{||\sigma_r\times\sigma_\phi||}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4r^2}}\begin{pmatrix}-2r\cos\phi\\-2r\sin\phi\\1\end{pmatrix}.$$ But since we are only interested in the unit normal along $\alpha_1$, we have $\phi=0$, ie
$$\vec{n}(\alpha_1(t))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4t^2}}\begin{pmatrix}-2t\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}.$$
With $\alpha_1''(t)=(0,0,2)$ and $\vec{n}\times\alpha_1'=\sqrt{1+4t^2}\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}$, we have
$$\kappa_g=\frac{\sqrt{1+4t^2}\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}}{(1+4t^2)^{3/2}}=0.$$
Therefore $\alpha_1(t)$ is a geodesic on $\sigma$.




Is the unit circle $\alpha_2$ a geodesic on $\sigma$?
$||\alpha_2'(t)||=\sqrt{\cos^2t+\sin^2t}=1$, therefore $\alpha_2$ is constant speed from the outset, without reparametrization. But the same calculation as above yields $\kappa_g=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$, ie $\alpha_2(t)$ is not a geodesic on $\sigma$.



To sum it up, we have to check if a curve has vanishing geodesic curvature, and if it does, it is a geodesic. A geodesic having constant speed is only a "byproduct" but not a prerequisite, which I incorrectly assumed.
